# How to download 10 most recent sent mails into ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I am using the below given code to download sent items into my access db. Though code works it loops through all the sent mails, but I want to stop loop after it performs the action for last 10 items in the sent items folder. I understand I can use either restrict function or do until but I am not clear in doing it could you help?

```
Private Sub sntml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim stfldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim stfldrItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dealer As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set stfldr = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ogmls")
Set stfldrItems = stfldr.Items
For Each Mailobject In stfldrItems
    With rst
        .AddNew
        !Subject = Mailobject.Subject
        !from = Mailobject.SenderName
        !To = Mailobject.To
        !Body = Mailobject.Body
        !DateSent = Mailobject.SentOn
        .Update
        Mailobject.UnRead = False
    End With
End If
Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set stfldr = Nothing
Set stfldrItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to sort emails by received time. Then read the top 10 emails and exit out of loop when done

```
Private Sub sntml()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim stfldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim stfldrItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim dealer As Integer
Dim emailCount as integer

Set db = CurrentDb
Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set stfldr = OlApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set rst= CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ogmls")
Set stfldrItems = stfldr.Items
stfldrItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"
emailCount=1
For Each Mailobject In stfldrItems

    With rst
        .AddNew
        !Subject = Mailobject.Subject
        !from = Mailobject.SenderName
        !To = Mailobject.To
        !Body = Mailobject.Body
        !DateSent = Mailobject.SentOn
        .Update
        Mailobject.UnRead = False
    End With
    emailCount = emailCount+1
    if emailCount > 10 then 
      Exit For
    end if

Next
Set OlApp = Nothing
Set stfldr = Nothing
Set stfldrItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! If you like the answer I would appreciate if you can up vote